# Best way to bootstrap the Golang install with an existing homebrew install

Tags: go, compilation, homebrew

The Go tool chain was rewritten in Go, requiring a prior Go compiler to exist to perform the install.

You can point to an existing compiler using the GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP environment variable.

In my situation I have Go already installed by Homebrew. Going forward I want to compile from the source and **not** by 'brew upgrade go'. I want to use the Homebrew install to compile the latest source, as it already exists on the system.

the following throws an error ("Cannot find packages")

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/golang/go/src
GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.2 ./all.bash
```

and so does this ("Cannot find /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.2/go/bin/go")

```
GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.2/go ./all.bash
```

but this works (mostly, except for me it fails with a Python _lldb.so plug-in error)

```
GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.2/libexec ./all.bash
```

What does the "libexec" do in this context?
and is there a better way to install golang with the prior compiler being from homebrew?

Comment: Your Go sources must **not** be under $GOPATH.

Comment: I thought all Go source code must be under a valid $GOPATH? also the homebrew install is just the binary I believe.

Comment: Your beliefs are wrong. Your _own_ code *should* be under GOPATH (to use the `go` tool). The compiler source *must* *not*.

Answer (score 2):

Post version 1.4 Go is written in go so you need to install something that can understand and compile go natively, often called the go toolchain.

Don't change anything else just install the latest 1.4 version and point GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP at this.  In my case I installed Go 1.4.3 and placed into a directory C:\Go143 and on windows did this
set GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=C:\Go143

All worked after that